# Propagation of standard deviation for random variable with Markov Property

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, markov-process, error-propagation

I have a discrete random variable, $X \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. Define the indicator function:

$$ 1_{k}\left(x\right) = 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=k$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases}$$

where, $x$, is a realization of $X$. Consider the following random variables:

$$N_k = \sum_{i=1}^{N} 1_{k}\left(x_i\right)$$

where $N$ is the total number of trials; $x_i$, is the realization of $X$ from the $i$-th trial, and $N_k$ is the number of trials which resulted in a value of $x_i=k$. I then define:

$$J_k=\frac{N_k}{N}$$

In this case $J_k$ is the fraction of trials which resulted in $x_i=k$. I would like to find the sample standard deviation of $J_k$. How can I do this?

I assume that it ought to be a function of the sample standard deviation of $X$, but I am unsure how the standard deviation propagates from $X$ to $J_k$ since we have $J_k=J_k\left(X\right)$.

Also, note that $\sum_{k=0}^3 J_k=1$. Essentially $J_k$ is an estimate of $\mathbb{P}\left(X=k\right)$, and I want to know how to get error bounds for this estimate.

One other important piece of information that I failed to mention earlier, is that the $x_i$ are in fact arranged on a hexagonal lattice, and there are local correlations, so that $x_i$ is correlated with its nearest neighbors. These correlations die out quickly though, so I think a Markov property assumption would be valid.

Comment: Each $J_k$ has a binomial distribution with expected value $\mathbb{P}(X=k)$.  Do you know the standard deviation of a binomial?

Comment: @Michael: That is a good insight. I suppose that I could use the measured $J_k$ as the expected value of binomial distribution and compute the standard deviation as $\sqrt{N J_k \left(1-J_k\right)}$. However, that would only work if each $x_i$ is a Bernoulli trial, right? In my case the $x_k$ are not independent, though I think I can safely assume a Markov property (i.e. that $x_i$ depends only on $x_{i-r}$ through $x_{i+r}$, where $r$ is small, something like 3 or so). Can I still use the Binomial approach?

Comment: No--and the question has become so vast that it is difficult to say anything useful here.